# How do I find color limits for qualitative colormaps in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a following code that generates a scatter plot:

```
plt.scatter(df['column_A'], y= df['column_B'], 
            alpha = .6, c = df['column_C'], cmap = 'Accent')
```

It generates [this chart where points are colored based on values from 'column_C'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrWic.png)

I am using qualitative colormap in cmap which automatically creates intervals on column_C and color the points accordingly. I can visually say that the grey group ranges from around 10 to the maximum in data (around 12) but I would like to access the exact numbers. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the colors range from the smallest to the largest values of `column_C`. For the colormap with `N` colors, there will be `N` segments, thus `N+1` borders which can be calculated with `np.linspace()`.

Here is some illustrating code. Both a colorbar with default ticks and one with ticks at the color borders are added.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': np.random.rand(100),
                   'column_B': np.random.rand(100),
                   'column_C': np.random.rand(100) * 20 - 8})
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Accent')
plt.scatter(df['column_A'], y=df['column_B'],
            alpha=.6, c=df['column_C'], cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()  # the default color bar
color_borders = np.linspace(df['column_C'].min(), df['column_C'].max(), cmap.N + 1)
plt.colorbar(ticks=color_borders)  # ticks at the color borders
plt.show()
```

[image: finding color borders in colorbar]